# Python: Cows and Bulls game

Tags: python, index-error

I am writing a code fora game which randomly generates a 4-digit number. Ask the user to guess a 4-digit number. For every digit that the user guessed correctly
in the correct place, they have a “cow”. For every digit the user guessed correctly in the wrong place is a “bull.” Every time the user makes a guess, tell them how many “cows” and “bulls” they have. Once the user guesses the correct number, the game is over. Keep track of the number of guesses the user makes throughout the game and tell the user at the end.

The code is below.

```
import random

rand=[random.randint(0,9) for n in range(3)]


user_guess=[input("Please guess 4-digit number: ")]

def game():
    count=0
    while True:
        guess=[i for i in rand]
        listnum=[i for i in user_guess]

        if guess == listnum:
            print("You won.")
            print("It took you "+str(count)+" guess.")
            break

        if guess != listnum:
            cow=0
            bull=0
            count+=1
            for x in range(0,3):
                if guess[x]==listnum[x]:
                    cow+=1

        if len(set(guess)&set(listnum))>num:
            bull=len(set(guess)&set(listnum)) - cow

        print("Cows: "+str(cow)+' Bulls: '+str(bull))

game()
```

But I am getting the following error after it asks the user to guess the number and takes the input. The error is given below.

```
Please guess 4-digit number: 1234

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-64a0b0d4d766> in <module>()
     41         print("Cows: "+str(cow)+' Bulls: '+str(bull))
     42 
---> 43 game()
     44 
     45 

<ipython-input-48-64a0b0d4d766> in game()
     33             count+=1
     34             for x in range(0,3):
---> 35                 if guess[x]==listnum[x]:
     36                     cow+=1
     37 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What mistake am I making here?

Comment: `listnum` will be a list with one element, whereas `guess` will be a list with 3 elements. `listnum[x]` will fail when `x == 1`

Comment: While this doesn't answer you question already, keep in mind that you are comparing characters to integers where your error occurs.

Comment: as things are set up now, `user_guess` (and therefore `listnum`) will probably only have one element, so trying to access its 1th or 2th element is not possible (hence "list index out of range"). maybe you want `guess[x]==listnum[0]`, or just have `listnum` be a scalar instead of a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of when a digit is a bull is a little bit unclear. Let's say your solution key is e.g. `[1, 8, 5, 8]` and your guess `8888`. The number 8 is present multiple times in the solution key. So you have 2 cows. But what is your expected output for bulls in this case? One possible solution (see below) would be to check if each guessed number is present anywhere in the solution key (even though it might already be a cow).

The solution below includes some of the remarks already mentioned by others (see post by @[Bill M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10643988/bill-m)).

**Possible solution:**

```
import random

def game(num_digits):
    # generate list of random integers of length num_digits
    listnum = [random.randint(0,9) for n in range(num_digits)]
    print("Solution key = " + str(listnum))

    count=0
    while True:
        count+=1
        print("~~~ Guess: " + str(count) + " ~~~")

        print("Please guess " + str(num_digits) + "-digit number: ")
        # transform input string (e.g. "1234") to list of integers (e.g. [1,2,3,4])
        guess = [int(i) for i in str(input())]

        if guess == listnum:
            print("You won.")
            print("It took you "+str(count)+" guess(es).")
            break

        else:
            cow=0
            bull=0

            for x in range(0,num_digits):
                if guess[x]==listnum[x]:
                    cow += 1
                elif guess[x] in listnum: # look if digit is somewhere else in the solution key (might already be a cow)
                    bull += 1

        print("Cows: "+str(cow)+" Bulls: "+str(bull))
        print("++++++++++++++++")

game(4)
```

**Example output:**

```
Solution key = [1, 8, 5, 8]
~~~ Guess: 1 ~~~
Please guess 4-digit number:
2288
Cows: 1 Bulls: 1
++++++++++++++++
~~~ Guess: 2 ~~~
Please guess 4-digit number:
8888
Cows: 2 Bulls: 2
++++++++++++++++
~~~ Guess: 3 ~~~
Please guess 4-digit number:
1858
You won.
It took you 3 guess(es).
```

Answer (score 2):

So it's basically a variant of Mastermind, eh?  Anyway, for `user_guess`, you have brackets around the entire return of `input`. Since input is a string, then this gives you back a list with just one item.  For example, if the user enters `1234`, then `user_guess` becomes the list `['1234']`, **not** `['1', '2', '3', '4']`. This means `listnum=[i for i in user_guess]` just gives you back `[1234]` (a list with one element, which is the number one thousand, two hundred thirty-four), **not** `[1,2,3,4]`.  So try removing the brackets you have around `input`.

Also, you should change your creation of `listnum` to `listnum=[int(i) for i in user_guess]`, since you're ultimately trying to compare integers, not strings.

Some other things I noticed:

- You tell users to use a 4-digit number.  So you should be using `range(4)`
- You ask the user to guess only once.  You should have the `input` statement in your function.
- Your counter for the number of guesses is off by one.  Try putting the `count += 1` right after the `while True`.
- The `guess=[i for i in rand]` seems redundant.  You could just use the list `rand` here.  Also, it seems counter-intuitive to call the secret answer "guess".
- In fact, since you have everything as a function, there's no need for a `while` loop.  You can just call the `game()` function again after a wrong guess, and use `return` when the user finally wins.
- For the bull count, you use a variable called `num`, but I don't see this defined anywhere.  Shouldn't this just be 8?  Also, consider the case where the bull count should be 4, or the secret answer is something like '1233': should a guess of '3354' give you two bulls?
- And a grammatical point: the answer you print says "It took you [however many] guess", not "guesses" if the number of guesses is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square-brackets from this line `user_guess=[input("Please guess 4-digit number: ")]`, as is creating a list with one entry, the user string input. which is probably related to `IndexError` as there is only *one* entry in the list, e.g. `['1234']`.

Another fix is convert the user string input into a list of integers, before the `while`-loop:

```
user_guess = input("Please guess 4-digit number: ")

def game():
    count=0
    listnum = [int(num) for num in user_guess]
    # or use `map`
    # listnum = list(map(int, user_guess))
```

The infinite-loop that happens after that is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

define input as string not as one elemented list with one string in it

user_guess=input("Please guess 4-digit number: ")

then split the list using a seperator

listnum= user_guess.split(',')

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

plus num is undefined in

if len(set(guess)&set(listnum))>num: